# ¿Cómo usar un bucle (loop) para exportar como .csv los resultados de aplicar una función a varias bases de datos?

Tags: r, bucle-for, function

Mi intención es usar un bucle con for para aplicar una función a varios datasets, y a su vez guardar los output como archivos .csv.

Voy a presentar un ejemplo sencillo, que estoy segura se puede resolver de otras formas, pero es solo para intentar ilustrar lo que necesito hacer con datos y funciones un poco más complicados:

Tengo los siguientes datasets:

```
df1 = data.frame(ID_INDIVIDUO = c("individo_1", "individo_2", "individo_3", "individo_4", "individo_5", "individo_6", "individo_7"), 
                 ciudad = c("Ciudad_A", "Ciudad_A", "Ciudad_B", "Ciudad_C", "Ciudad_C", "Ciudad_D", "Ciudad_A"))

df2 = data.frame(ID_INDIVIDUO = c("individo_1", "individo_4", "individo_5", "individo_6", "individo_7"), 
                 ciudad = c("Ciudad_A", "Ciudad_C", "Ciudad_C", "Ciudad_D", "Ciudad_A"))
```

Y la siguiente función:

```
mi_funcion <- function(x){
  Casos_ciudad_A <- x %>% filter(ciudad == "Ciudad_A")
  return(Casos_ciudad_A)
}
```

Para hacer una lista de los datasets a utilizar, hago:

```
archivos <- mget(ls()[grep("df", ls())])
```

Y hasta acá llego. Puedo ver los resultados que quiero haciendo:

```
for (i in archivos){
  print(mi_funcion(i))
}
```

Pero no logro exportar los resultados de cada dataset a dos archivos separados. Este fue mi intento, que da error:

```
for (i in archivos){
  write.csv(mi_funcion(i),paste(names(archivos [i]), ".csv", sep = ","))
}
```

Específicamente, el error es: "Error in files[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'". Les agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda que pueda orientarme en esto. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Natalias, bienvenida. Traté de reproducir el error y el código que compartiste no incluye la definición del objeto `files`, que al parecer tiene mucho que ver con el error que recibes. ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta para incluirlo? De manera general una sugerencia sería crear el vector de nombres de archivo antes de usarlos en el bucle y luego llamarlo ahí por su posición. De ese modo es más fácil el debugging: los pasos que fallan, fallan de uno a la vez.

Comment: Hola mpaladino! Gracias por hacérmelo notar, recién edité la pregunta; el objeto era "archivos", no "files". La idea era que se genere el nombre del .csv a partir del nombre de los dataframes en `archivos`, pero ahora pienso que tal vez names no era la función adecuada a usar. Si genero un vector `nombres <- c(df1,df2)`, ¿qué sería llamarlo al bucle por su posición?

Comment: No encuentro una solución al problema del bucle, me parece que es un problema de entornos de ejecución. Quizás sería mejor iterar por posición (seqalong(archivos)) más que por nombres. Le encontré una solución bastante simple `iwalk(archivos, ~write.csv(.x %>% mi_funcion(), file = paste0(.y, ".csv")))` . `iwalk` es una funcional que aplica una función sin generar output (en este caso para R la escritura en disco no es output estrictamente) a cada elemento de una lista. Es del estilo de  `lapply()`, pero está en la librería `purrr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bienvenida. Creo que el problema es que usas a la lista misma como iterador. Entiendo que en R se puede hacer (aunque se vea como código de Python más que de R), pero la práctica más común es sincronizar el bucle usando la posición. Entonces tienes que generar explícitamente el iterador.

Este bucle funciona.

```
for (i in seq_along(archivos)){
  nombre = paste0(names(archivos)[i], ".csv")
  #print(nombre)
  out = mi_funcion(archivos[[i]])
  #print(out)
  write.csv(out, file = nombre)
  }
```

Usa `seq_along()` para generar una secuencia de enteros que va desde 1 hasta `length(archivos)`. Por ese índice itera `for` y se sincroniza la lista `archivos` con los nombres de la lista `archivos`. Creo que ese era el problema, en el subset de `names(archivos)[i]` le estabas pasando el data frame como `i`, y no `i` como numero de índice. `names(archivos)` es una cadena de caracteres, el subset se tiene que hacer con números o con otra cadena de caracteres que haga match con los nombres.

Si prefieres usar programación funcional en lugar de bucles una alternativa es esta:

```
iwalk(archivos, ~write.csv(.x %>% mi_funcion(), file = paste0(.y, ".csv")))
```

`walk()` es una funcional. Es similar a `lapply()`, se encarga de pasar otra función con una sintaxis `~fun(.x)` sobre una lista. Cada elemento de la lista se evalúa en la función como `.x`. La peculiaridad de `walk()` es que no produce output propiamente dicho y entonces es mejor para usarla cuando interesa producir un side effect como en `~print(.x)`, `~write.algo(.x)`, `~plot(.x)`.

`iwalk` es similar, excepto que permite utilizar a `.y` como segundo argumento de la función. En este caso `.y` siempre son los nombres de la lista `.x`. No hace falta llamar a `names(.x)`, ya están ahí como `y.` Es conveniente para casos como este, también sirve para hacer muchos gráficos y poner los títulos, titular también tablas, etc.

Comment: Excelente, ambas opciones funcionan perfecto al adaptarlas a mi script de trabajo, muchas gracias por la respuesta y la explicación!